# Tracing previous question from list

Tags: support

I had an earlier question on updating of Hinduism but am not able to find it among questions list/discussions. Can you please help me find it? Thanks.

Comment: Which question? Can you be more precise?

Comment: Thanks. I think it is somewhat like *Conservative Hinduism did not reform or update enough?* [was on hold] Oct 2016.

Comment: Unanswered questions with 0 rep or low and off topic questions will be deleted by system automatically.

Comment: Here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15346/36 It was closed on October 9, and then automatically deleted by the Community bot on October 29.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15346/277) was deleted by [system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) as `RemovedAbandonedClosed`.

Visit [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) for more information.

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.
>
> This check is run every day across all sites.

You can look at your [recently deleted questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1182) (only those posted in past 60 days) from your [profile](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/1182/narasimham?tab=questions) or (only your own posts) by advance searching `deleted:1` or `deleted:yes` after getting [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege.